# SMS notification with Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, notifications, sms

We are looking out for an SMS service that works well with Reactjs. Initially, we had on eyes on SNS by AWS but found out that is pretty inconsistent. If anyone could suggest to me which would be the best SMS provider that's well with react.

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-send-sms-messages-node-js

Comment: Each modern provider have REST API. ReactJS have many methods to use of rest api. We used https://www.infobip.com [link](https://www.infobip.com/docs/api#channels/sms)

Answer (score 1):

try out [twilio](https://www.twilio.com) they are very good I have been using their service and it's quite impressive